# Ascending recursion until file is found

Tags: shell, recursion, sh, zsh, prompt

First of all I'm very new to shell scripting. But I'm starting to love it more and more.

I really enjoy working on the Terminal, which why I started looking into customizing it for my needs by creating a personal prompt. You know, pro devs - pro prompts :-P

I'm pretty much satisfied with it at the moment. It has all the basic information that you would expect a prompt to have.

But I would love to add a non-standard "feature" to my prompt, but my newbieness is kicking my ass.

What I would love to do, is to create a method which looks for a specific file - in my case `composer.json` - in the current directory. If it's not found, it should jump up one level and look for it there. If it's not found there, it should jump up another level again and again and again until it finds the file.

At some point you'll probably hit the root `/` and then it should just abort.

The thing is, I want to be able to extract version numbers from a few specifically installed packages from the `composer.lock` file and show it in my prompt.

I don't seem to have a problem just looking for a file in the current directory, but it's the recursively ascending part that's problem.

I'm currently using the ZSH shell. Not sure if that provide some other features to achieve this than Bash.

Hope some of you incredible devs can help a shell fanboy out.

If I haven't made myself clear enough or if there is some information that you require that I haven't provided, don't hesitate to mention it and I'll do whatever it takes to give it.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more on `The thing is, I want to be able to extract version numbers from a few specifically installed packages from the composer.json file and show it in my prompt.` with a sample input and expected output?

Comment: @Inian When I'm in a folder where the file `composer.lock` is I can run the following command:

`composer show -i | grep "laravel/framework"`

Which returns:

`laravel/framework  v5.3.22 The Laravel Framework.`

And it's that **v5.3.22** I want to extract and show in my prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am kind of confused ... you say you are searching for `composer.json` but are talking about `composer.lock` ??? So below I will give you a script that finds composer.**lock**, you can change the `file`-variable at the beginning of the script if you want to change which file you're looking for!

I assumed your command `composer show -i | grep "laravel/framework`" would work in any directory the file composer.lock is found as you said in your comment.
So if it has to be done without changing the current directory, there are 2 options:

1. The cleanest way: push the current directory to the stack with `pushd` and before exiting pop the directory back with `popd`. Based on [this website](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_6.html) we shouldn't call pushd without argument

   > One difference is the way pushd is handled if no arguments are given. As in csh, this exchanges the top two elements of the directory stack

   You could then try this:

   ```
   file=composer.lock
   unset failure
   # pushd actually current directory and change to current directory
   pushd .

   while [ ! -f "$file" ]
   do
       if [ "$(pwd)" != "/" ]
        then
           cd ..
       else
           failure=true
           break
       fi
   done

   if [ -z "$failure" ]
     then
       echo Found file in $(pwd) 
       # Your command!
       composer show -i | grep "laravel/framework"
       popd
   else
       echo File $file could not be found! >&2
       popd
       exit 1
   fi

   exit 0
   ```
2. The other option is to hold a variable that holds the directory we've reached so far. This will allow to search for the file without changing directory at all!

   ```
   file=composer.lock
   unset failure
   cpath=$(pwd)

   while [ ! -f "$cpath/$file" ]
   do
       if [ "$cpath" != "/" ]
        then
           cpath=$(cd $cpath/.. && pwd)
       else
           failure=true
           break
       fi
   done

   if [ -z "$failure" ]
     then
       echo Found file in: $cpath
       # do something with $cpath ... 
   else
       echo File $file could not be found! >&2
       exit 1
   fi

   exit 0
   ```

It works in `sh` and `bash`. As I don't have a `zsh` installed, I couldn't try it out in `zsh` but I think it should work there too. I'm not sure though
You can leave out the `echo Found file in $(pwd)` if you want to. I had it there for test purposes

Good luck

Comment: Yeah I mixed the two files together. Sorry about that. `composer.lock` is the file that contains the version of the installed package.

I tried to update the question as quickly as possible with the correct file name.

Thank you for your answer. I'll give it a spin! :D

Comment: @j-baoby Both yes and no. Since I'm running the function in a `precmd` hook for my prompt, it actually changes the directory, which it shouldn't. It should just looked for the file without changing directory, so I tried to modify your code and ended up with this: https://gist.github.com/rugaard/9a1517a3b45fe39d5a7f6b5fb36af68c - But now my problem is that since I add `../` everytime to the path I'll never hit the `/` I'm looking for, which means it's basically an endless loop now. Need to figure out a way to detect when I'm at the root or a way to move up levels without actually changing dir.

Comment: I see now. I didn't know about the context in which the command would be executed. It then changes indeed: it is true that if it is run as a function and not as a script changing directories is not a good idea at all. I have 2 options in mind. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I've edited my answer. I gave 2 options: the first option saves the current directory on the directory stack and pops it back at the end; the second option won't change directory at all during execution of the script but your command has been left out at the end

Comment: I figured out a different way which actually works, but I'll accept your answer, since you pretty much lead  me in the right direction and I wouldn't have been able to fix it without you :) Solution: https://gist.github.com/rugaard/449b0578d66bdc010feb9bbb6947c036 - Just need a put of cleaning and optimizing. Currently it has a bit of speed penalty :P

Comment: Thank you! Good you were able to find a solution too :) I would also mention that your little speed penalty could be resolved with the use of the directory stack as in my first option. Good luck!